# javascript recursive function returns data when using debugger, but return undefined without

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function calling multiples functions, each result of function is use for the next one.

One of the function is recursive, and when I put a breakoint on the return statement, I get a result.
The result is store in a variable, which is then use as a paramter for another function. But when I put a beakpoint before calling the next one, the variable if undefined.

Below my code which will be clearer than my explainations I hope.

**function calling multiples functions :**

```
let calculateW = (settedCandles) => {
    
    try {
            
        let topAndBottomOnly = candlesController.getOnlyTopAndBottoms(settedCandles);
        
        let topAndBottomConsecutive = candlesController.getConsecutiveTopAndBottom(topAndBottomOnly);

        let potentialWs = _getPotentialW(topAndBottomConsecutive);

        let confirmedWs = _confirmW(potentialWs, settedCandles);

        return confirmedWs;
        
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error("[wController][calculateW]" + error);
    }
}
```

**the recursive function :**

```
if(candles != undefined && candles.length > 0 ){

    let consecutiveTopAndBottoms = candles;

    try {        

        let nbrOfTopBottom = 0;

        for (let i = 0; i < consecutiveTopAndBottoms.length; i++) {
         [ ... ] 
       }
if(!_arrayContainsConsecutivesTopAndBottoms(consecutiveTopAndBottoms)){

            //added delay to avoid cpu "overheat" error
            // await utils.delay(10);
            getConsecutiveTopAndBottom(consecutiveTopAndBottoms);

        }else if(_arrayContainsConsecutivesTopAndBottoms(consecutiveTopAndBottoms)){

            return consecutiveTopAndBottoms;
        }
        
        
    } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error);
    }
}else{
    throw new Error("[candleController][getConsecutiveTopAndBottom] - no candles or no setted candles");
}
```

Comment: A `return` statement only returns from the current call, not from the entire recursion stack. You are ignoring the result of the `getConsecutiveTopAndBottom(consecutiveTopAndBottoms)` call, and in that branch of the `if` statement you never `return` anything leading to `undefined`.

Comment: @Bergi, indeed that's correct, I added a return on the recursive call and it worked. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Bergi said,
The recursive call was missing the returned statement.

Thanks again for your help